# Programmatically cause Undefined Instruction exception

Tags: gcc, arm, inline-assembly, cortex-m

I want to cause an ARM Cortex-M3 Undefined Instruction exception for the test of my test fixture. The IAR compiler supports this with inline assembly like this:

```
asm("udf.w #0");
```

Unfortunately the GNU CC inline assembler does not know this opcode for the NXP LPC177x8x. It writes the diagnostic:

```
ccw3kZ46.s:404: Error: bad instruction `udf.w #0'
```

How can I create a function that causes a Undefined Instruction exception?

Comment: According to http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/I1010015.html blx from thumb16 is not supported by M3 and "always faults".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some extra info...

One of GCC's [builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) is

> > void __builtin_trap (void)
> >
> > **This function causes the program to exit abnormally**. GCC implements this function by using a target-dependent mechanism (**such as intentionally executing an illegal instruction**) or by calling abort. **The mechanism used may vary from release to release so you should not rely on any particular implementation.**

Its [implementation for ARMv7 is](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/master/gcc/config/arm/arm.md):

```
(define_insn "trap"
  [(trap_if (const_int 1) (const_int 0))]
  ""
  "*
  if (TARGET_ARM)
    return \".inst\\t0xe7f000f0\";
  else
    return \".inst\\t0xdeff\";
  "
  [(set (attr "length")
    (if_then_else (eq_attr "is_thumb" "yes")
              (const_int 2)
              (const_int 4)))
   (set_attr "type" "trap")
   (set_attr "conds" "unconditional")]
)
```

So for ARM mode gcc will generate `0x7f000f0 (f0 00 f0 07)`and for other modes `0xdeff (ff de)` (comes handy when disassembling / debugging).

[Also note that](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-12/msg00405.html):

```
these encodings match the UDF instruction that is defined in the most
recent edition of the ARM architecture reference manual.

Thumb: 0xde00 | imm8  (we chose 0xff for the imm8)
ARM: 0xe7f000f0 | (imm12 << 8) | imm4  (we chose to use 0 for both imms)
```

For [LLVM](http://llvm.org/klaus/llvm/blob/master/lib/Target/ARM/ARMAsmPrinter.cpp) `__builtin_trap` values generated are `0xe7ffdefe` and `0xdefe`:

```
case ARM::TRAP: {
  // Non-Darwin binutils don't yet support the "trap" mnemonic.
  // FIXME: Remove this special case when they do.
  if (!Subtarget->isTargetDarwin()) {
    //.long 0xe7ffdefe @ trap
    uint32_t Val = 0xe7ffdefeUL;
    OutStreamer.AddComment("trap");
    OutStreamer.EmitIntValue(Val, 4);
    return;
  }
  break;
}
case ARM::tTRAP: {
  // Non-Darwin binutils don't yet support the "trap" mnemonic.
  // FIXME: Remove this special case when they do.
  if (!Subtarget->isTargetDarwin()) {
    //.short 57086 @ trap
    uint16_t Val = 0xdefe;
    OutStreamer.AddComment("trap");
    OutStreamer.EmitIntValue(Val, 2);
    return;
  }
  break;
}
```

Comment: Beware that `__builtin_trap()` is treated as a `noreturn` function, so if you're planning to use it like a breakpoint and resume execution at the instruction after, that's not going to work.  The compiler won't have generated instructions for later C statements on that path of execution.  But yes, for other use cases it's exactly what you want.

Answer (score 15):

Building on *Masta79*'s answer:

There is a "permanently undefined" encoding listed in the ARMv7-M architecture reference manual - ARM DDI 0403D ([documentation placeholder, registration required](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0403c/index.html)). The encoding is 0xf7fXaXXX (where 'X' is ignored). Of course instruction fetches are little-endian, so (without testing):

`asm volatile (".word 0xf7f0a000\n");`

should yield a guaranteed undefined instruction on any ARMv7-M or later processor.

Comment: Cortex-M3 has only Thumb mode. It is however Thumb with Thumb-2 extensions, meaning there are both 16-bit and 32-bit instructions. The "permanently undefined" one is a 32-bit one.

Comment: I don't think you should manually change the endian here. The assembler will automatically swap endian as appropriate.

Comment: @tangrs: yes, the assembler will automatically byte-reverse the word, but 32-bit Thumb instructions are made up of 16-bit entities, which also need to be in little-endian order.

Comment: when you put `.word` that word also written as little endian, so you shouldn't reverse it.

Comment: auselen is correct here, `a000f7f0 strdge  pc, [r0], -r0`, `f7f0a000        undefined instruction 0xf7f0a000`. Please fix your answer to ".word 0xf7f0a000\n".

Comment: Using `.inst` looks like a even better. https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/as/ARM-Directives.html#ARM-Directives

Comment: Sorry guys, now fixed. Nudged on by @Patater.

Comment: It works in thumb mode. Is there any way to trap it for a user space program?

Answer (score 10):

There are different official undefined instructions in [1] (look for UDF; `.` below can be replaced with any hex digit):

- `0xe7f...f.` - ARM or A1 encoding (ARMv4T, ARMv5T, ARMv6, ARMv7, ARMv8)
- `0xde..` - Thumb or T1 encoding (ARMv4T, ARMv5T, ARMv6, ARMv7, ARMv8)
- `0xf7f.a...` - Thumb2 or T2 encoding (ARMv6T2, ARMv7, ARMv8)
- `0x0000....` - ARMv8-A permanently undefined

There are others, but these are probably as future-proof as it gets.

As for generating the code that triggers it, you can just use `.short` or `.word`, like this:

- `asm volatile (".short 0xde00\n");` /* thumb illegal instruction */
- `asm volatile (".word 0xe7f000f0\n");` /* arm illegal instruction */
- `asm volatile (".word 0xe7f0def0\n");` /* arm+thumb illegal instruction */

Note that the last one will decode to `0xdef0`, `0xe7f0` in thumb context, and therefore also cause an undefined instruction exception.

[1] http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.architecture.reference/index.html

[2] DDI0487D_b_armv8_arm.pdf

Comment: Does any flavour of ARM assembly language have mnemonics for any of these, the way x86 has [`UD2`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/UD2.html)?

Comment: ARM documents reference `UDF`, but I don't know if that's recognised by any assemblers. gcc/gas does not recognise it.

Comment: And for ARMv8 / aarch64 / arm64, there are `BRK`, `HLT`, `HVC`, `SMC` and `SVC` documented in *C3.1.4 Exception generation and return* of DDI0487A (ARM ARM). Not quite like `permanently undefined`, but could be useful.

Comment: @PeterCordes GNU `as` as of Binutils 2.29.51.20170811 does assemble `udf 0x1234` into `f4 23 f1 e7` (in unified syntax, at least).

Comment: @domen dosen't ARMv8 A64 also describe an UDF instruction at encoding 0000XXXX? I don't understand why GNU GAS 2.29 not have a mnemonic for it however.

Comment: @CiroSantilli I've updated the answer. I can't find a reference with a quick search, but wouldn't ARMv8 A64 be backwards compatible with A1 encoding as well?

Comment: Now I understood why it is not in GAS: the A64 one only appears on a very recent version of the ARMARM: https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/db/DDI0487D_b_armv8_arm.pdf but not in https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/ca/DDI0487C_a_armv8_arm.pdf I don't know in general, but in this case the A64 encoding for UDF != A32 ones.

Answer (score 8):

The thumb-16 version of the permanently undefined instruction is `0xDExx`. So you can do this in your code to trigger the exception:

```
.inst 0xde00
```

Reference: ARMv7-M Architecture Reference Manual, section A5.2.6.

(Note that 0xF7Fx, 0xAxxx encoding is also permanently undefined, but is a 32-bit instruction.)